# geoserver geowebcache bad request

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I use geoserver war 2.4.5 on tomcat and internal geowebcache 1.5.0. My server is MS Server 2008. All software works on 64 bit. My geoserver work perfectly with wms,wfs but when i want to do tile cache i take badrequest error from openlayers. My Confugiration and error message are below. How can i fix this problem?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post the OpenLayers code that is making the gwc request?

Comment: i dont write code i use tile layers >preview>epsg4326/jpegorpng

Comment: Ok now I understand about the OL code. I cannot tell from your post which layer(s) are throwing the error. Can you preview tiger:tiger_roads?

Comment: All layers give bad request error also tiger:tiger_roads on preview. additional information is my geoserver on tomcat work on port 82.

Comment: I suppose that the problem comes from the port :82. All services should automatically use the configured port but the geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher errors prove that something goes wrong. Geoserver users mailing list may be better to offer help for this case. Describe your environment and how you installed Geoserver into Tomcat and port :82.

Comment: i configure tomcat port 82 to 8080 from servel xml; everythig work but geowebcachwe still gives same error